# 信用度の獲得に伴い授与されるバッジはメタサイトにおいてどのような条件で授与されますか？

Tags: サポート, メタ, バッジ

ヘルプセンターによれば、メタサイトの信用度はメインサイトと同期されているものの、バッジは別々に授与されます<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)</sup>。また、ここにはメタサイトで得た票は信用度に影響しない、とも書かれています。投票が信用度に影響しないならば、信用度の変動は起きないということになります。

> ### 「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)</sup>
>
> メタ用に別のアカウントを作成する必要はありません。スタック・オーバーフローにログインすると、メタサイトにもログインしたことになり投稿できます。
>
> メタでの票はユーザーの信用度には影響しません。メタでの信用度は スタック・オーバーフローでの信用度と同じ（毎時同期されます）ですが、バッジは個々に得られます。メタに参加するには、1点の信用度が必要です。

そのため、信用度の変動が授与条件となっているバッジ (秀才, 異才, 鬼才バッジ) はメタサイトにおいて授与されないと考えました。しかし、授与履歴を確認すると[過去に秀才バッジが授与されていました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard)。

これらのバッジには何か信用度に依存しない授与条件がありますか？また、授与条件を満たしているのかどうかはどのように確認出来ますか？

> ### 参加バッジ<sup>[[2]](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)</sup>
>
> - 秀才 1 日で 200 点 (1 日の最大値) 以上の信用度を獲得したことが 1 回あった 1 獲得
> - 異才 1 日で 200 点以上の信用度を獲得したことが 50 回あった
> - 鬼才 1 日で 200 点以上の信用度を獲得したことが 150 回あった

Answer (score 4):

信用度はメインサイトにおいては投票によって増減し、これはそのままサイト内で出来る事 = **[権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)** に直結しています。一方でバッジは主に **回数の記録** であり、権限とは直接結びつきません。

メタにおける行動では権限の変動は無いが、バッジの授与に関連した各種回数の記録はキチンと裏で行われている…という事だと思います。

なお、バッジが授与されるまでの進捗については、自分自身のプロフィールページで目標にするバッジを選択する際に確認することができます。

**次のバッジ > 目標にするバッジを選択**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**バッジの選択画面**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: とはいえメタで「200 点以上の信用度を獲得」とは一体……？　という意味合いの質問なのかなと思っていました。メインサイトだと信用度はプラスされたりマイナスされたりし、お礼を使えば +10 以外のプラス変動もありえるので、単なる回数とは言えなさそうです。